# Threaded Chat Session between 2 users using C++

Tags: c++, sockets

I want to build a simple chat session between two users, not more. I know that this should be done using socket programming, but to be honest i haven't worked in this domain yet so this will be my first.

I need to know where to start from and was wondering if there are any samples that you suggest i start from.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Windows, then I would suggest looking at this site to learn the WinSock API.

http://tangentsoft.net/wskfaq/

Section 6.1 contains some example code which I found very helpful when first learning socket programming.

Answer (score 0):

Start by designing the protocol and basic layout. Will the two clients connect to each other directly? Will there be a server involved? Will the clients be specific software? Or will they be browsers? Will they communicate with raw binary data? Or will it be text? Or XML?

Comment: I want it to be as simple as it could get, so clients connecting to each other would be enough. The chat content will be english text only nothing more but this text will be compressed so the final data will probably be binary

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much every socket programming library has a simple chat example.  Find one and adapt it to your needs.

[Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/) is usually friendly to newbies, it has a lot of examples, reference, and users who discuss it.